# Sitecore reindex AlreadyClosedException: this IndexWriter is closed

Tags: solr, indexing

Reindexing locally works fine, but when I reindex upstream I get this error:

```
org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: this IndexWriter is closed
```

[image: Indexing manager error]

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://urbansitecore.blog/2018/11/20/solr-6-6-2-exceptions-while-rebuilding-large-indexes/), it's a resource issue. You need to locate the `solr.in.cmd` file in your solr directory and uncomment and increase the values on this line:

[image: solr.in.cmd]